# kml click issue

Tags: javascript, maps

I have two kml files.  One contains polygons for counties, and the other pins on the map.
I need to show the polygons and on top the points.  The pins need to show the pop ups when clicked.

When i set it up with first loading the polygons and then the points, the points are not click-able and the pop-ups do not appear.

When it set it up the other way the points become click-able but they appear under the polygons

here is an example

pins are on top of the polygons and do not work
http://dev.ppdtrainingevent.wsits.com/Content/index.html

pins are under polygons  (might have to zoom in to see them) clicking usually works
http://dev.ppdtrainingevent.wsits.com/Content/index2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The partial solution came down to combining the two kml files.  After enabling preserveViewport the map pretty much worked ok.  There was still a problem with balloons covering up pins and preventing clicks through transparent areas.

Finally i gave up and used V2.  In v2 there are no problems.